# Why am I not able to write to/read from custom AXI lite peripheral's registers

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado, zynq, vivado-hls

I am working with a Zynq board where a custom AXI 4 lite slave peripheral is created and then added from the IP Repository. Then these blocks have been successfully connected with `Run Connection Automation`. Then bit stream was generated successfully.

Further the SDK was launched. There was a blank C project with simple code for the ZYNQ PS working already. This code was altered by following the pdf "**Designing a  custom AXI4 lite Slave Peripheral**" (the one shown in the following image).

> Write and read functions for the custom AXI slave peripheral

[image]

Now the SDK executes without any error but when I observe the addresses on SDK monitor, there is no data written into it (as shown in the following image).

[image]

Where could I have gone wrong or what have I missed? 
Working with vhdl on Vivado 16.2.

What I have already tried: **-processing with XSDB console with command**

```
mwr -force 0x43C00000 0x01234
```

no change there.

> Checked the Vivado Address editor to contain the same base address
>   included `xparamters.h`

Thank you very much in advance..

update: the `xparameters.h` file did not have the same base and high address as the vivado address editor. So tried with changing the 'memory region' in linker script to RAM from DDR [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkenG.png) ,

now when observed in the 'variables' window, when clicked on 'Step Into' button, i do get the expected change in values[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXCel.png)  ..
The XSDB console output and Memory monitor output remain unchanged though.

The `hardware platform specification` file does show the custom AXI lite with the right expected base and high address.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcrFJ.png)

Comment: It could be anywhere.. First I would check reset input (Should be Active Low) to the AXI Lite Peripheral. It would help if you could post the AXI Lite vhdl code.

Comment: You might need to use the debugger/chip scope to see what's happening on the bus. Something is definitely happening, as else the PS would hang after this operation. It needs a ready response from the PL after such an operation: Just try to runs the code without the PL being loaded. It should hang then.

Comment: @VinayMadapura : thank you for replying! .. I created the custom AXI lite peripheral using the create and package IP wizard.
Hence i am guessing problems like code or reset active low should not be causing a problem

Still.. i did check the reset and itseems to be active low.

Comment: @JHBonarius ..thank you for replying!! I will not be able to debug using Integrated logic analyser (ILA ) and I do not have the AXI BFM simulation license. Earlier i had brought out the FCLK signal to board LED and checked with LED and oscilloscope if it works, but i have just 3 LEDs and moreover AXI LITE are all connected with Zynq PS M_AXI signals and hence not brought out on "TOP_WRAP" module.                  I did try to run code without PL and yes, it does continue to sdk ..

Comment: That's weird. AXI MM requires the addressed slave to respond. So if you try to read and write to a non-existing address, which will of course never response, the r/w action will wait indeterminately. If this does not occur, then you're maybe not writing to or reading from the correct address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hardware_platform specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8xef.png)

- One of the reasons that were causing this problem was a different hardware platform associated with the debug configurations wrt to the one you want to use.

As we make some changes in the IPs and update them, when the bitstream is exported to SDK, a new hardware platform gets created . Say if the older one is `TOP_WRAPPER_hw_platform_0`, now a new one is created `TOP_WRAPPER_hw_platform_1`.

This new platform should be updated in the debug configuration settings `Hardware platform`.

further in debug config settings the following needed to be ticked on
Under Target Setup

- Reset entire system
- Program FPGA

Under Application tab

- Download Application
- Stop at 'main'